# Setting an Apache environment variable to the value of another Apache environment variable

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

I need to a set an environment variable in Apache to have the same value as another existing environment so that it is passed through the proxy to Tomcat using AJP. What I thought would work doesn't:

```
SetEnv AJP_REDIRECT_URL %{ENV:REDIRECT_URL}
```

The simply end up with the value in the AJP_REDIRECT_URL being the string "%{ENV:REDIRECT_URL}". I have tried all sorts of combinations here but none work, I always simply end up with the string I put as the value being available at the other end.

Comment: Thought I was getting somewhere with the following

   SetEnvIf REDIRECT_URL "(.*)" AJP_REDIRECT_URL=$1

However SetEnvIf seems to restricted only a limited set of environment variable, so while this looked promising still can't get it to work. Anyone get any ideas?